# Menu Item break text

Tags: html, css, menu, menuitem

I have a problem. It might look simple, but I can't fix this.
I have a menu, that shows me 10 items. The 9th item is not aligned in right way, cause has 2 lines of text.
How can I fix this?

[JSFIDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/nhAKg/)

**HTML:**

```
<ul style="list-style:none; width: 615px;">
<li style="display: inline-block;"><a class="butao" href="http://www.ahighplay.org/pt/gca/index.php?id=34&preview=1">DFC Portugal</a>

</li>
<li style="display: inline-block;"><a class="butao" href="http://www.ahighplay.org/pt/gca/index.php?id=30&preview=1">Processo DFC</a>

</li>
<li style="display: inline-block;"><a class="butao" href="http://www.ahighplay.org/pt/gca/index.php?id=72&preview=1">Como Participar</a>

</li>
<li style="display: inline-block;"><a class="butao" href="http://www.ahighplay.org/pt/gca/index.php?id=70&preview=1">Calendário</a>

</li>
<li style="display: inline-block;"><a class="butao" href="http://www.ahighplay.org/pt/gca/index.php?id=71&preview=1">Regulamento</a>

</li>
<li style="display: inline-block;"><a class="butao" href="http://www.ahighplay.org/pt/gca/index.php?id=26&preview=1">FAQ's</a>

</li>
<li style="display: inline-block;"><a href="http://www.ahighplay.org/pt/gca/index.php?id=25&preview=1" class="butao">Vídeos</a>

</li>
<li style="display: inline-block;"><a href="http://ahighplay.org/pt/gca/index.php?id=61&preview=1" class="butao">Notícias</a>

</li>
<li style="display: inline-block;"><a href="http://www.ahighplay.org/pt/gca/index.php?id=27&preview=1" class="butao" style="line-height: 20px">Parceiros / Patrocinadores</a>

</li>
<li style="display: inline-block;"><a href="http://www.ahighplay.org/pt/gca/index.php?id=28&preview=1" class="butao">Contactos</a>

</li>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this settings to make the buttons stay on the same line.

```
ul li {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/itay1989/nhAKg/1/)

Further more, is not advisable to use inline styles (and it repeats itself on every list item). You should move that setting to the CSS, so your code would be:

```
ul li {
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: inline-block;
}
```